Banach space divergent sequence.
Let $X$ be a real Banach space, and let $\{ x_n \} \subset X$ be a divergent sequence. Is it always true that there exist $\delta > 0$ and a strictly increasing sequence $\{ n_k \} \subset \mathbb{N} $ such that
$$
\| x_{n_{k+1}} - x_{n_k} \| > \delta, \quad k = 1, 2, \dots?
$$
I can prove that the conclusion is valid in the following situations:

$\left\{ x_{n} \right\}$ is unbounded.

Inductive selection $$\left| \left| x_{n_{k+1}} \right| \right| \geqslant \left| \left| x_{n_{k}} \right| \right| +1,k=1,2,\cdots,$$
then $$\left| \left| x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_{k}} \right| \right| \geqslant 1,k=1,2,\cdots .$$

$\left\{ x_{n} \right\}$ has a limit point.

Let $a$ be the limit point, take the neighborhood $U$ of $a$ so that $U^{c}$ contains  infinite number of points in $\left\{ x_{n} \right\}$. Just take the points near $a$ and the points outside $U$ in sequence.
So the most difficult situation is that $\left\{ x_{n} \right\}$ is an isolated bounded closed set.

You already asked this question and it was closed https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5012453/divergent-sequences-in-banach-spaces

This question is similar to: Divergent sequences in Banach spaces. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It seems the OP did not understand that they should edit their previous question to add context and then request reopening, instead of asking a new question. Regardless, the new question has sufficient context to me, so I don’t think closing it is justified.

Suppose that for some $\delta > 0$, for each $i$, there is some $j > i$ such that $\|x_i - x_j\| > \delta$. Then obviously such a subsequence can be formed. Start with $n_0=1$ and for each $k$, let $n_{k+1}$ be such a $j$-value for $i = n_k$.
So if the claim is false, then for every $\delta > 0$, there is some $i$ such that for all $j > i, \|x_i - x_j\| < \frac{\delta}2$. In particular, for any $j, k>i$, we have $\|x_j - x_k\| \le \|x_j - x_i\| + \|x_i - x_k\| < \delta$. This means $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy and thus converges.
